# django 2 Custom User: Attribute Error (password not passing/hashing properly)

Tags: django, django-custom-user

I have implemented a custom user setup for django 2. However I can't seem to find out source of this error that occurs anytime I attempt to register.

```
AttributeError at /register/

'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

When I get this error, the password is passed without a hash and not saved to the db, while the other values pass through fine.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
            return self._create_user(email, password)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    objects = MyUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib import messages
from . forms import RegisterForm


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'authenticate/home.html', {})


def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, ('Welcome Back'))
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.success(request, ('No account matches those credentials. Please try again.'))
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html', {})


def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, ('Successfully logged out'))
    return redirect('home')


def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, ('Welcome to Keto2Go!'))
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'authenticate/register.html', context)

def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('You have updated your profile'))
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'authenticate/edit_profile.html', context)


def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Your password has been updated.'))
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'authenticate/change_password.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from . models import User


class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("email is taken")
        return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data and self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The password does not match ")
        return self.cleaned_data


class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data and self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The password does not match ")
        return self.cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserAdminChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password')

    def clean_password(self):
        return self.initial["password"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In registration, you are trying to authenticate using keyword argument `email` but authenticate does not have any kwargs `email`, it takes `username` and `password`(Unless you override it in custom backend). So try like this(Just like your `login_user` view):

```
authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
```

See in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#available-authentication-backends) for more details.

Also you password will not be saved in hash format, because you are directly saving it to Database using `save` method without using `set_password`. You need to update the save method in `Registration` form(Just like your `UserAdminCreationForm`)

```
 def save(self, commit=True):
    # Save the provided password in hashed format
    user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

Comment: thank you for explaining it with code I've already implemented